# Could not load type 'Common.Logging.Factory.AbstractCachingLoggerFactoryAdapter'

Tags: nuget, log4net, common.logging

I just updated my nuget packages for `Common.Logging.Log4Net`. Since then I keep getting the following error:

> Could not load type
>   'Common.Logging.Factory.AbstractCachingLoggerFactoryAdapter' from
>   assembly 'Common.Logging, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e'

Here is a list of each nuget package that is linked to `Common.Logging` as well as version:

- Common.Logging - 2.2.0
- Common.Logging.Core - 2.2.0
- Common.Logging.Log4Net - 2.0.1

In my web.config I have the following bit:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
   <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  //...//

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.0.0" newVersion="2.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  //...//

  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4net">
        <arg key="configType" value="FILE-WATCH" />
        <arg key="configFile" value="~/log4net.config" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>
</configuration>
```

**How can I fix this?**

I've tried changing:

```
<factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4net">
```

to (added version of the Common.Logging.Log4net.dll [201])

```
<factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4net201">
```

and that didn't work.

Comment: As a note this error was being thrown when you call `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I've found the answer to my question and wanted to share the answer with anyone experiencing the same issue.

It looks like between `Common.Logging 2.1.2` and `Common.Logging 2.2.0` the developer made a change to create a new library `Common.Logging.Core`. The `Common.Logging.Log4Net` package hasn't been updated to support the new change according to the Common.Logging development (GitHub) site.

- Ryan Wentzel comment mentions he needed to rollback to 2.1.2 version of `Common.Logging` for his BaseSpace project: https://github.com/basespace/basespace-csharp-sdk/pull/8
- TypeLoadException explained as a logged issue: https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/issues/48

Answer (score 0):

Another point of view that might help some people:

From Common.Logging 3.0, the developers made a change of how they handle version dependencies, as an example, the assembly Common.Logging.Log4Net would no longer be supported, each of the frameworks would now need a version specific reference.  Thus, for Common.Logging.Log4Net, it would be Common.Logging.Log4Net1213 for the latest of this writing.

Using nuget, you could get this by:

```
Install-Package Common.Logging.Log4Net1213
```

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/wiki/Common.Logging-Packaging-and-Versions).